# Python scoping mutable vs immutable

Tags: python, immutability, mutable, scoping

First I'm going to start like everyone else. I'm new to python. My teacher gave me the problem:

```
def f(a, b, c):  
    a    = 1 
    c    = b 
    c[0] = 2 
a = 10 
b = [11, 12, 13] 
c = [13, 14, 15] 
f(a, b, c) 
print a, b, c
```

It prints:

```
10 [2, 12, 13] [13, 14, 15]
```

I understand that a stays at 10 because integers are immutable, but I don't understand why b changes and c doesn't.

Comment: I'd also point out that this doesn't have to do with the data types being mutable/immutable. As the answers below point out, this is about variable assignment. [The data model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) page discusses that difference.

Comment: what is confusing you is just the variable names, I guess. give the ones outside the function different names i.e. x,y,z;so you wanna call f(x,y,z), and print x,y,z. And i am sure it won't be that hard to see.

Answer (score 4):

```
c    = b 
c[0] = 2
```

Since you're setting `c` to point to `b`, You could just as easily do this:

```
def f(a, b, unused): # notice c isn't in the parameter list  
    a = 1
    c = b # c is declared here
    c[0] = 2 # c points to b, so c[0] is b[0]
```

Now it's obvious that `c` is always the same as `b`, so why not just remove it:

```
def f(a, b, unused):
    a = 1
    b[0] = 2
```

And now it's clear that you're changing the first element of `b` and not doing anything to `c`, and remember, this is functionally identical to the original.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to understand the variables as pointers under the hood:

```
def f(a, b, c):  
    a    = 1 # a is a single scalar value, so no pointing involved
    c    = b # point the local "c" pointer to point to "b"
    c[0] = 2 # change the 2nd value in the list pointed to by "c" to 2
```

When you call f(a,b,c), only b actually gets changed. The "c" variable inside the function implementation is different from the "c" implementation outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

`a` does not retain the value of 10 because it is immutable.  It retains the value of 10 because when you call `a = 1` in the local scope of `f()` you create a new variable.

When you call `c = b` inside `f()`, the local `c` becomes a local reference to the mutable object represented by `b`.  When you re-assign the values in that mutable object the change is reflected in the original object.